# How can i solve this error. i want to complete trigger assignment

Tags: salesforce

> Error:Apex trigger AccountAddressTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountAddressTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.AccountAddressTrigger: line 6, column 1

while solving Create an Apex trigger for Account that matches Shipping Address Postal Code with Billing Address Postal Code based on a custom field.
I got the above mentioned error
I had write correct logic but still get the error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I highly recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the best answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really poor, post the code you've writte so far and/or link to that challenge (what is it, a [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com) task? Homework? Job interview?)

My guess is that your trigger should operate as "before insert, before update", not "after". `Before's` are for all kinds of validations and field prepopulation and one of notable features is that you don't need to explicitly write `update myrecords;` - you get save to database for free. `After's` are more for side effects like creating related records, anything that makes sense only after you generated record's Id.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. and also sorry for poor question as i am new on this platform, i did't know how to write good question. I will try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class contactTriggerHandler {
    public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Contact> newList, Map<Id,Contact> oldMap) {
        Set<Id> contactsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact con: newList) {
            // Check if phone field is changed
            if (oldMap.get(con.Id).Phone != con.Phone) {
                // Update mobile field with phone value
               // con.MobilePhone = con.Phone;
                contactsToUpdate.add(con.Id);
            }
        }
        
        if (!contactsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            // Asynchronous update using a future method
           // updateMobilePhones(contactsToUpdate);
           contactTriggerHandler.updateMobilePhones(new List<Id>(contactsToUpdate));
        }
        
    }
    @future
    public static void updateMobilePhones(List<Id> contactsIds) {
        List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactsIds];
        for (Contact con : contactsToUpdate) {
            con.MobilePhone = con.Phone;
        }
        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

I really hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**